# Multiple event listeners

Tags: javascript, click, listener, display

OK so i have the following questions:

Should i add an event listener directly to the `parent element`(modal popup box), where this element have `3 buttons`(2 for closing the tab, 1 for submitting data).

And in the `listener function` to assign some `class methods` like so and manipulate the whole functionality (submit data and display UI):

```
document.getElementById('weather-modal-container').addEventListener('click', modal);

function modal(e) {
  ui.closeModal(e);
  weather.submitData();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Or should i add 2 `click listeners` to the parent element one for closing the modal and one for submitting the data.

```
document.getElementById('weather-modal-container').addEventListener('click', closeModal);
document.getElementById('weather-modal-container').addEventListener('click', submitData);
```

Or one listener directly to the `parent element` to manipulate the `UI` and another listener for the button that's inside the container.

```
document.getElementById('weather-modal-container').addEventListener('click', closeModal);
document.getElementById('button-inside-container').addEventListener('click', submitData);
```

Comment: Please ask one question per question

Comment: Jokes on you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, and what about  only 1 event listener for All ?

```js
const MyDialog = document.querySelector('#weather-modal-container')

MyDialog.onclick=e=>{
  let role = e.target.dataset.role
  if (role)
  {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.clear()
    console.log (role)
    
    switch (role){
      case 'submitData':
        console.log ('something is :', MyDialog.something.value)
        // stuff about submiting data
        break;
      case 'closeModal':
        // stuff about close modal
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#weather-modal-container { display: block; width: 30em; padding: 1em; border: 1px solid grey;}
a[data-role] { color: red; float: right;}

#weather-modal-container button { float: right; margin: 0 .3em 0 0 }
```

```html
<form id="weather-modal-container">
  <a href="#" title="closeModal" data-role="closeModal">X</a>

  <p>Bla bla bla bla</p>
  <input type="text" placeholder="with something" name="something" value="hello">

  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org" title="wikipedia" > wikipedia</a>
  <br>
  <button data-role="submitData">Send</button>
  <button data-role="closeModal">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: So the `data-` attribute is a better approach than using 
`e.target.className/id === something { do something }`;

Comment: There is no absolute truth, and in any case computer science is not a religion. The best code is the one that is the easiest to understand, being as concise as possible. For me to multiply the event handlers is a heresy, especially in this case since the version HTML5.2 will soon introduce the tag <dialog>

Comment: Ok sir your example is a good and understandable approach. I will use that case. Is easier than having a `class` for the closing buttons and one `id` for the `submit button`